# Specify a variable as an integer

Tags: evaluation, variable-definitions

I have a formula that always evaluates to a certain number for any variable `X` under one condition that `X` is an integer and greater than 0.

So how can I evaluate `Func[X]` and specify that X is an integer greater than 0? is there a way to do that? I tried saying `Func[Round[X]]` but it didn't work, it just used `Round[X]` as a variable instead of understanding that it means `X` is an integer.

Ok I will give exactly what I'm trying to do, it's fairly simple:

$p=
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0.5 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
;$

$\text{mainWin}=\{0,12.4461,24.8921,37.3382,49.7842,62.2303,74.6763,87.1224,99.5685,112.015\};$

$u=\{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0\};$

Now I'm evaluating:
$(u.\text{MatrixPower}[p,x]).\text{money}$ where $x$ is a positive integer

This will always evaluate to: **37.3382** which if you notice is the fourth entry in $money$ which is also the state that we started with.

Now I want to know if mathematica can figure that out (that it always evaluates to this number) if I indicate that $x$ is a positive integer. If I just use $x$ normally:

```
(u.MatrixPower[p, x]).mainWin // Simplify
```

I get:

```
37.3382 + (2.77553*10^-24 - 1.91762*10^-31 I) (-0.5)^
x - (1.77636*10^-15 - 1.59872*10^-14 I) (-0.116393 - 0.396276 I)^
x + (3.55271*10^-15 - 1.95399*10^-14 I) (-0.116393 + 0.396276 I)^
x + (7.10543*10^-15 - 4.73403*10^-15 I) (-2.20245*10^-16)^
x - (5.68434*10^-14 + 2.27918*10^-16 I) 0.732786^x
```

As you can see I just want to get rid of that imaginary part

The answers here are quite educational (I'm new to Mathematica) but unfortunately they don't give the required outcome.

Just for the interested; this is modelling the outcome of a gamble where you have p as the probability matrix, your initial state is number 4. and what I'm doing here is guaranteeing that I get one outcome no matter how many times I gamble, and that outcome is equal to whatever I started with.

This is Mathematica code:

```
p = \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", "", GridBox[{
{"1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0.5`", "0", "0.5`", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0.5`", "0", "0", "0", "0.5`", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0.5`", "0", "0", "0", "0.5`", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0.5`", "0", "0.5`", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0.5`", "0", "0.5`", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1"}
},
GridBoxAlignment->{
        "Columns" -> {{Center}}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, 
         "Rows" -> {{Baseline}}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}, "Items" -> {}, 
         "ItemsIndexed" -> {}},
GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {
Offset[0.27999999999999997`], {
Offset[0.7]}, 
Offset[0.27999999999999997`]}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, "Rows" -> {
Offset[0.2], {
Offset[0.4]}, 
Offset[0.2]}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}, "Items" -> {}, 
         "ItemsIndexed" -> {}}], "", ")"}],
Function[BoxForm`e$, 
    MatrixForm[BoxForm`e$]]]\);
mainWin = {0, 12.4460563, 24.89211259, 37.33816889, 49.78422519, 
   62.23028148, 74.67633778, 87.12239407, 99.56845037, 112.0145067};
u = {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
(u.MatrixPower[p, x]).mainWin // Simplify
```

Comment: Please post a minimal example of your problematic code. While you're at it, you may want to check out [this question's answers regarding function definiton](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) and [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForFunctions.html).

Comment: I don't see a simple way to copy your matrix `p` -- would you please include a copy of that in *Mathematica* code so I don't have to waste time on it?

Comment: Ok I added my code

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I discovered to my surprise that if you right click in the bottom right part of the LaTeX matrix above you get a MathJax menu with the option to copy as MathML which Mathematica can deal with. The resulting matrix is: {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 
  0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}

Comment: @Spacemonkey Just use `Chop` to get rid of the small complex numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Another method is to use [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternTest.html) along with specifying the [`Head`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23093/52):

```
f[x_Integer?Positive] := (* ... *)
```

this is similar in intent to using `Condition`, [above](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23094/52), but I find it is more straightforward for simple conditions. Of course, you can combine them using

```
f[x_Integer] /; x > 0 := (* ... *)
```

Answer (score 3):

One interpretation of the question is to specify that a function only holds for an integer argument. This can be done like this:

```
f[x_Integer] := x^2
```

which specifies that the function only applies when x happens to be an integer. So for instance, `f[3]` evaluates to 9, but `f[2.5]` just returns `f[2.5]` unevaluated.

Answer (score 2):

How about defining the function like this:

```
Func[x_] /; IntegerQ[x] && x > 0 := (* Function definition *)
```

This guarantees that only integers greater than zero will be accepted by the function `Func`

Answer (score 1):

In your revised problem, it looks like you are calculating some properties of a Markov process with state transition matrix $P$. There is a large and powerful set of functions in Mathematica 9 that deal with Markov processes. See, for instance `DiscreteMarkovProcess` and `MarkovProcessProperties` which give things line the steady state distribution (which seems to be closely related to what you are calculating).

Fort he lower part of your problem, define the function:

```
f[x_]:=Chop[37.3382 + (2.77553*10^-24 - 1.91762*10^-31 I) (-0.5)^
x - (1.77636*10^-15 - 1.59872*10^-14 I) (-0.116393 - 0.396276 I)^
x + (3.55271*10^-15 - 1.95399*10^-14 I) (-0.116393 + 0.396276 I)^
x + (7.10543*10^-15 - 4.73403*10^-15 I) (-2.20245*10^-16)^
x - (5.68434*10^-14 + 2.27918*10^-16 I) 0.732786^x]
```

then you can see the simplified form using

```
Chop[f[x]]
```

which gives:

```
37.3382 + 0^(1 + x)
```

So as long as x is a positive integer, this is just 37.3382. In case this is not obvious,

```
Simplify[37.3382 + 0^(1 + x), Assumptions -> x > 1]
```

which returns just the constant.

Comment: Thanks a lot that's quite useful, but is there away to say that x is always positive so that Mathematica understands that it will always evaluate to 37.3382?